# Difference between ISymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences and ISymbol.Locations

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

What is the difference between the [DeclaringSyntaxReferences](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/ISymbol.cs,7f9fc305c0940c9b) property and [Locations](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/ISymbol.cs,6fdf20baf08270e2) property in the [ISyntax](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/ISymbol.cs) interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clue to the answer is in the `<remarks>` comment section:

> The syntax node(s) that declared the symbol. If the symbol was declared in metadata or was implicitly declared, returns an empty read-only array.

Which means, that `Locations` also returns metadata reference declarations and implicitly declared locations. You can see evidence for that in the [LocationsTests.cs](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.Symbol.UnitTests/Symbols/Source/LocationTests.cs,31) file:

```
var c = s.GetTypeMembers("C", 0).Single() as NamedTypeSymbol;
var obj = c.BaseType;
Assert.Equal("MetadataFile(CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary)", obj.Locations[0].ToString());
```

where `c` is the `class C` in:

```
namespace N.S{class C{int F; void M(int P}{}}
```

so `obj` is `System.Object`. This makes sense, because you don't have any actual source code, and thus *syntax*, in the compilation, that would define `System.Object`.