# Using Roslyn, how to check if class comes from a local project, not the BCL or Nuget (etc)?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I want to write a Roslyn code analyser; which needs to work out if an `ObjectCreationExpression` is creating an object from a local class (either in the current project or a project in the current solution); or if the class comes from somewhere else, like the Base Class Library or a Nuget package etc.

**How do I tell where a class comes from in Roslyn?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only get that with the help of the semantic model. You can get the symbol for the constructor, and the check where the type comes from via [Locations or DeclaringSyntaxReferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38775807/difference-between-isymbol-declaringsyntaxreferences-and-isymbol-locations), e.g.:

```
// ObjectCreationExpression node == ...;
// SemanticModel model = ...;
var symbol = model.GetSymbolInfo(node).Symbol; // the constructor symbol
var type = symbol.ContainingType; // the class symbol
var isFromSource = type.DeclaringSyntaxReferences.Length > 0
```