# How to know if a symbol is declared in the solution?

Tags: c#, roslyn

When analyzing C# source code in a Roslyn `DiagnosticAnalyzer`, I have an `ITypeSymbol`. How can I decide whether this type is declared in the source or is only referenced through assembly references?

My current solution is to check if the symbol has any `DeclaringSyntaxReferences`. This works great inside Visual Studio. However, when I'm doing the analysis in an MsBuild execution, my results are not accurate. The problem is that MsBuild builds each project one-by-one, so if the type symbol was declared in another project, then `DeclaringSyntaxReferences` will be empty.

Is there a way to differentiate "Project References" from "Assembly references"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39200779/using-roslyn-how-to-check-if-class-comes-from-a-local-project-not-the-bcl-or-n/39202311#39202311

Comment: @m0sa thanks, but this doesn't answer my question. I know this is the way to do it in a VSIX, but this doesn't work with nuget and msbuild across projects.

Comment: This feels like an instance of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to do if you knew such a distinction?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski, my analyzer identifies classes that violate some behavior, and I want to tell the users to modify them. But only if they can modify it, meaning they have the source for the symbol. The problem is that I see different behavior inside and outside Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this method helps:

```
private bool GetSource(ISymbol symbol, out string filePath)
{
    var baseLocation = symbol.Locations.FirstOrDefault();
    filePath = "SPECIFY CURRENT SYNTAX TREE FILE PATH";

    if (baseLocation == null)
        return false;

    var baseLocationPath = baseLocation.ToString();

    if (baseLocationPath.Contains("SourceFile("))
    {
        baseLocationPath = baseLocation.ToString().Replace("SourceFile(", "");
        filePath = baseLocationPath.Substring(0, baseLocationPath.LastIndexOf("[", StringComparison.Ordinal));
    }
    else if (baseLocationPath.Contains("MetadataFile("))
    {
        baseLocationPath = baseLocation.ToString().Replace("MetadataFile(", "");
        filePath = baseLocationPath.Substring(0, baseLocationPath.LastIndexOf(".dll", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 4);
    }

    return baseLocation.IsInSource;
}
```

Comment: The `IsInSource` property only checks if there's a syntax tree for the location. And across projects there's none if running through msbuild.